# NullReferenceException в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, .net

Консольное приложение, принимающее на вход строку и возвращающее ответ из тхт файла. 
Визуал студия никаких ошибок при сборке не выдает, но консоль возвращает пустую строку. При отладке выявлено, что `string[] answerList = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");` - выдает NullReferenceException. Не могу правильно истолковать ошибку - текстовый файл с ответами есть в директории.

```
static string Trim(string str, char[] chars)
    {
        string strA = str;

        for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            strA = strA.Replace(char.ToString(chars[i]),"");
        }
        return strA;
    }


    static string Ans(string q)
    {
        string tr = ")(:^^=!?";
        var ans = "";
        q = q.ToLower();
        q = Trim(q, tr.ToCharArray());
        string[] answerList = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < answerList.Length; i+=2)
        {
            if(q == answerList[i].ToLower())
            {
                ans = answerList[i+1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Write("Ваш вопрос: ");
            string q = Console.ReadLine(); //Ввод вопроса
            Console.WriteLine("Бот сказал: " + Ans(q) + "\n"); // вывод
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ларчик просто открывался

```
string[] answerList = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

Comment: пометьте хотя бы свой ответ как правильный)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы не знаете, какой размер вы хотите заранее, используйте контейнер с динамическим изменением размера, например **List**:

```
List<string> answerList = new List<string>();
```

В.NET 4 вы можете сделать это более эффективным с **File.ReadLines** c точки зрения памяти, используя **File.ReadLines** а не **File.ReadAllLines** - это поток файлов вместо загрузки всего этого в память для начала.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но он не подходит - у меня заранее известное количество ответов и они записаны в тхт файл. Принцип перебора даже тхт файла идет на заранее известной позиции ответа.

Comment: @ТимурАлексеев , а что у вас в массиве ответов после считывания файла, можете посмотреть ?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я нашел ответ, все гораздо банальнее. Ниже напишу

Comment: Хорошо, что нашли)